# SICP exercise 1.18

Tags: sicp

What is wrong with my solution ?

```
(define (halve x) (/ x 2))
(define (double x) (* x 2))

(define (mult-iter acc a b)
  (cond ((= b 0) acc)
        ((even? b) (mult-iter acc (double a) (halve b)))
        (else (mult-iter (+ a acc) a (- b 1)))))

(define (* a b)
  (mult-iter 0 a b))
```

When I run this interpriter fails:

```
1 ]=> (load "e1.18.scm")

;Loading "e1.18.scm"... done
;Value: *

1 ]=> (* 2 2)

;Aborting!: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

"Paper" debugging didn't help:
(* 2 2) -> mult-iter 0 2 2 -> (b is even so) mult-iter 0 4 1 -> (b isn't even) -> mult-iter 4 4 0 -> (b is equal to 0) 4.

The result should be 4, where do I get infinite recursion?

Comment: Please copy the statement of the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in here:

```
(define (double x) (* x 2))
```

The `*` procedure that you're using is the same you're defining below! that leads to a circular recursion. In general, it's not a good idea to name a procedure using an existing built-in's name. You should rename your new definition:

```
(define (mul a b)
  (mult-iter 0 a b))
```

Or alternatively, define `double` without using `*`, but I prefer the previous approach:

```
(define (double x) (+ x x))
```